# Gerar password aleatório

Tags: node.js

Olá, verifiquei que existem as bibliotecas [generate-password](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-password) e [password-generator](https://github.com/bermi/password-generator) para geração de password aleatório. Porém, importar uma biblioteca só para isso, talvez não seja uma boa ideia. Será que existe alguma forma no próprio node para fazer isso ?

Comment: +1. Há casos também que concordo que, bibliotecas para coisas simples, são desnecessárias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe uma técnica conhecida e referida [por exemplo aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9719815/2256325) que faz isso de maneira prática:

```
function gerarPassword() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).slice(-10);
}
```

Neste caso gera uma password convertendo em base36 e depois usando somente os ultimos 10 caracteres.

Um exemplo de aplicação e 10 testes seriam assim:

```
var testes = Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map(gerarPassword);
console.log(JSON.stringify(testes));
// dá 
[
    "ywnfa5g66r",
    "0go0d1v2t9",
    "s52wukgldi",
    "t9c8hvvx6r",
    "z5ygvw8kt9",
    "uazwcanhfr",
    "g91b5wxw29",
    "lbn4hg2e29",
    "ey101thuxr",
    "eo62fswcdi"
]
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wwrgmf7L/

Comment: Respondi primeiro! sou mais ninja!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters tu respondeste com 2 linhas e depois editaste com o resto do conteúdo. Eu respondi com a resposta completa e com jsFiddle... quem é o ninja? :)

Comment: Você é o ninja, por ter reparado isso :D +1

Answer (score 2):

Eu utilizaria o `Math.random` combinado com o `toString(36)`

```
Math.random().toString(36).substring(0, 7)
```

O parâmetro 36 passado para `toString`, deve ser um inteiro entre 2 e 36 especificando a base utilizada para representar os valores numéricos.

Ao utilizar `substring` estamos limitando o número de caracteres que serão retornados. Ou seja, gerei uma senha aleatório com, no máximo, 7 caracteres.

Veja um exemplo no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/W5BsOa)